# Android navigation drawer custom background selected drawable

Tags: android, background, customization, navigation-drawer, drawable

I am currently experimenting with customizing android themes. I want to create an app with an app drawer that looks like Spotify's. 
For example, when highlighted, I want it to highlight only the left part instead of the whole background, as shown on the screenshot.

[image]

This is my current situation.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It's custom view with list adapter. You can have a 2dp width view and height matching parent in your listview row.

Comment: How would I start to do that? I have the default list adapter from android when I created the drawer activity.

Comment: How can extend a BaseAdapter and override the getView method and inflate your custom row in it.